# Saving the background of a button?

Tags: java, android-studio, save, sharedpreferences

I have a Toggle Button that has a background. I want to save that background state when the user either closes the application or navigates away from the MainActivity. I managed to save the state of the Toggle boolean value but not the image background of the toggle itself. Anyone have any ideas? Please see my code below for further info.

```
private ToggleButton mtoggle;

public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String M_TOGGLE = "mtoggle";

private boolean SwitchON_OFF;
```

Here are my methods for saving,loading,and updating. Again saving the state of the toggle boolean value is no problem. Just don't know where to begin saving the state of the background of the Toggle button, (The background changes from a grey one to a yellow once pressed and visa versa). Need to save each state of that.

```
public void saveData(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putBoolean(M_TOGGLE,mtoggle.isChecked()); // saving toggle state no problem.


    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

public  void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);

    SwitchON_OFF = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(M_TOGGLE,false);

}

public void updateViews(){
    mtoggle.setChecked(SwitchON_OFF);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:-

According to your requirement you can use if condition.

Drawable files:-
for both colours:-

**1st:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/sky_blue"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<solid android:color="@color/message_fragment_button" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dp_10" />

</shape>
```

**2nd:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/sky_blue"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<solid android:color="@color/sky_blue" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dp_10" />

</shape>
```

And in Java:-

```
if (MessageConfirmed.equals("Yes")) {
        btn_confirm.setText("Confirmed");
        btn_confirm.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
R.drawable.confirm_button_blue));
        btn_confirm.setEnabled(false);

    } else {
        btn_confirm.setText("Confirm");
        btn_confirm.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
R.drawable.confirm_button_green));
        btn_confirm.setEnabled(true);

}
```

But yes you need to define initially background colour into your XML file.